# Passing parameters from connected app

Tags: visualforce, connected-apps, canvas

I have this visualforce page below and I'm using the canvasApp, along with it I'm also passing the `parameters` but some reason I'm unable to see those parameters in the third party app  what is it that I need to do in order to pass the parameters to canvasApp?

I'm aware that `parameters` are embedded in the context and when I debug the size of the parameters is showing 0

```
<apex:page >

    <apex:canvasApp developerName="CanvasMvcHelloWorld" 
         height="1000px" width="800px" 
        parameters="{vst_cli: '1293'}"/>

</apex:page>
```

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: How are you testing the Connected app ?Are you using previewer to test?

Comment: yes I'm using `Canvas App Previewer` to test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is how you are testing the canvas App.Canvas App Previewer simply sends signed request and user context and not parameters from your actual visualforce page

Since the parameters are passed only when visualforce is rendered .You should test this via Visualforce page to see the parameters and not use canvas App previewer .

Go to your page URL `salesforce_domain/apex/vfname`

Comment: if i try to test through `/apex/my_canvas_app` then i'm getting this error `Oops, there was an error rendering Force.com Canvas application [CanvasMvcHelloWorld].
Force.com Canvas can not locate an installed canvas app with the namespace [ttc] and API name [CanvasMvcHelloWorld].` what might invoke this error?

Comment: @NickKahn The problem you are now describing is totally different question .Check for developer name ?This means the developer name is incorrect and does not match .

Comment: hmmm i know i am getting totally different error now after trying directly going through apex/....  which i have not see this before... let me look

Comment: since i was not testing directly through VFP so I haven't see that error and the developerName was not correct thats why I was getting that above error... and now I can see my parameters thanks 1+

Comment: developerName=mycanvas_api_name

Comment: @NickKahn Yes thats correct .Also I saw you asked question on canvas previously and have not closed the thread .If that answers please mark as answered to help community